# MTPA Reference block settings (Simulink)?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, matlab-deployment

I am failrly recent to MATLAB and SIMULINK. I am trying to use to Motor Control blockset in Simulink to implement an FOC algorithm. I am using the MTPA Reference block for Simulink to calculate the Id and Iq currents for me but there are parameters in the block I don't understand. What is the difference between max current and base current ? How do you calculate stator d-axis inductance ? Is this given in the motor datasheet or do we have to calculate it ? And if so, how do I do it ? What is the per-unit (PU) in I/P singal units ? Why would you choose this rather than SI units ? Also is the permanent magnet flux linkage meant to be in the motor datasheet ? I am modelling the iPower Gimbal motor GBM2804H-100T. Please your help would be really appreciated.
MTPA Reference Documentation link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/mtpacontrolreference.html

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your question today.
Request you to try posting on MATLAB Central for faster response.

Anyway, apologies for delayed response. Pl find your answers below.

*What is the difference between max current and base current ?*

- Max current is motor's rated current. This is also explained in the parameters tab [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/mtpacontrolreference.html).
- Base current is reference value used while working with PU System. This is usually higher than motor's rated current. Usually, we consider peak ac current as measured by ADCs, to be base value. But you're free to change it to any reference value. It may be same as Max current, may also be different.

*How do you calculate stator d-axis inductance ?*

- For starters, Ld = Ls (total stator inductance) for Surface PMSMs. It's different for IPMSMs.

*Is this given in the motor datasheet or do we have to calculate it ? And if so, how do I do it ?*

- It's usually specified by manufacturers. However, the real motor may have variation w.r.to. design specifications. Hence, you need to run some tests and measure it.
- We have a tool to measure the motor parameters. See [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/gs/estimate-motor-parameters.html) for more details.

*What is the per-unit (PU) in I/P signal units ?*

- You can choose to work with SI units or PU system in the algorithm. We recommend working with PU System for efficient code generation.
- For more details, refer to [this page.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/gs/per-unit-system.html)
- Try simulation/code-generation of [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/gs/field-weakening-control-mtpa-pmsm.html). Type the variable name 'PU_System' at MATLAB Command Prompt for details related to base values.

*Why would you choose this rather than SI units ?*

1. Computational efficiency for embedded systems.
2. Scalability.

- This is also answered on [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/gs/per-unit-system.html).

*Also is the permanent magnet flux linkage meant to be in the motor datasheet ?*

- No. This is also measured via the parameter estimation tool.
- You can also compute the PM flux linkage from backEMF constant or torque constant using the equations mentioned on [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/surfacemountpmsm.html).

I hope this was useful.
Stay safe!

--
Darshan Pandit | MathWorks

[image: MathWorksLogo]

For more resources see: [MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/)